# How to get notifications (if any) from NotificationChannel?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat

If app decides to delete some particular `NotificationChannel` I want to know if there are any `Notification` to prevent its deletion with the channel. Like if channel has at least one `Notification` app should not delete such channel. So how to know if channel has notifications?